# Running the same pytest with different setup

Tags: python, pytest

So I want to run the same test multiple times (preferably in parallel, but thats another story), just with different variables for the setup. I need to test the same thing on different devices, so I have to change the device name on every setup. Here is how far I've got, but its not working:

```python
import pytest
from appium import webdriver

device_list = ["x", "y", "z"]

class TestLogin():

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("device_setup", device_list)
    def setup(self, device_setup):
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://172.18.0.2:4444/wd/hub',
                desired_capabilities= {
                    'deviceName': device_setup,
                    })

    def teardown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_a(self):
        # Do something

    def test_b(self):
        # Do another thing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot parametrize the `setup` method, but you can use an auto-used fixture instead:

```
device_list = ["x", "y", "z"]

class TestLogin:

    @pytest.fixture(params=device_list, autouse=True)
    def device_setup(self, request):
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://172.18.0.2:4444/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities={
                'deviceName': request.param,
            })
        yield
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_a(self):
        # Do something
```

This will execute each test with each parameter of the device list, as if you put the `mark.parametrize` decorator before each function.

UPDATE:
If you want to run the setup only once for each parameter, you can use a session-scoped fixture instead:

```
class TestLogin:

    @pytest.fixture(params=device_list, autouse=True, scope="session")
    def device_setup(self, request):
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://172.18.0.2:4444/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities={
                'deviceName': request.param,
            })
        yield
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_a(self):
        # Do something

    def test_b(self):
        # Do something
```

This will run the setup 3 times (once for each driver parameter) instead of 6 times.

Comment: Thanks for answering on this a few weeks ago. I've got another question. I want to run the driver setup only once before all the tests, and teardown after they are complete. And that for every device. I've tried with scope='session' but it is not working together with the params flag in the fixture, even after putting the driver setup into a conftest.py

Comment: Well, you have to setup your driver at least once for each parameter - so session scope should be ok. I will add this to the answer.

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks. But unfortunatly only if going with sequential testing (device for device). If we try to use pytest-xdist with ```pytest -n X(number of workers)``` it doesn't work with session scopes

Comment: I don't have experience with `pytest-xdist` - I would suggest you write a new question with that specific problem, so someone else can help you.